# How to use a spring bean as a custom ID generator

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I want to specify a custom id generator for an entity in a spring data jpa project.

I know that I can use something like:

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "id_generator", strategy = "com.example.generator.CustomIdGenerator")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "id_generator")
```

What I'm wondering is whether it's possible to somehow wire a spring bean as the strategy rather than a concrete class.

E. g.

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "id_generator", strategy = "bean", bean="beanName")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "id_generator")
```

Comment: That's a custom HIBERNATE generator ... not JPA.

Comment: Started working on the topic. Assuming you use LocalSessionFactoryBean, you can get through the Hibernate ServiceRegistry and inject beans (or the application context itself). Trying it now, let me see if I sort it out

Answer (score 2):

As Neil mentioned, this is Hibernate annotation. AFAIK Hibernate doesn't have (and I bet wouldn't ever have) any dependency on Spring. Therefore it can't take bean from Spring's IoC container as attribute.

Comment: Granted but my example was simply "thinking out loud".  I'm still wondering if there's a "spring" way to annotate an entity so that a spring bean can be used as an id generator.